# Advertising or legit question/answer pair?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, scope

I have encountered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580801/telerik-control) and I am struggling to find any usefulness in it!

The title is not great and the question is of very low quality.
Answers are basically a bunch of links to the product. And they are not even good links! I mean, an example or demo would have been better. And it's top 1 by relevance when looking for Telerik on SO.

Should we delete this question for advertising? Or should we let it live as a legitimate and useful question?

I know the question is closed as off-topic, but its visibility still buzzes me.

Comment: I highly doubt it's advertising in disguise, but it's not really worth keeping either way.

Comment: It should have been deleted *years* ago. Thanks for bringing it up; the garbage will be taken out shortly.

Comment: I have few post like this one.. Where is the queue for them ?

Comment: If they aren't already closed, just flag them. Use the link underneath the tags -> "should be closed" -> pick a reason that makes sense.

Comment: [Google cache link with the question](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:stackoverflow.com/questions/5580801/telerik-control)  for those <10k rep.